# Google apps script - Importing sheet values from another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pulling my hair out a little trying to write a conditional Google apps script for Google sheets. The sheet has 5 tabs. Basically, the sheet gets it's data from a google form. Clients fill the form out and it populates our "Master" tab of the sheet in question.

Here's where I'm hung up:
The form is used for teachers to refer students to specific administrators. Whoever is controlling the form needs to be able to assign a specific row of data to a specific administrator, which each have their own tab set up. They do this by selecting, from a drop down, which admin they want to assign the row to.

So, if row 2 is assigned to "Miranda," Certain data would get moved over to the "Miranda" tab. For the sake of argument lets say column D and E of that particular row would get moved over to column A of the "Miranda" tab.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
function importStudent() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var master_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
    var miranda_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Miranda");
    var columnT = master_sheet.getRange("T1:T").getValues();
    var columnD = master_sheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues();
    var columnE = master_sheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues();
        for(var i = 0; i <= columnT; i++) {
            if (columnT[i][0] === "Miranda") {
                var miranda_row = (miranda_sheet.getLastRow() + 1);
                var active_row = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(columnT[i].getRow());
                var selectionFirst = columnD.setActiveRange(active_row:columnD);
                var selectionLast = columnE.setActiveRange(active_row:columnE);
                var fullName = selectionFirst + " " + selectionLast;
                fullName.copyValuesToRange(miranda_sheet, 1, 1, miranda_row, miranda_row);
            }
        }
}
```

The below code is broken, and i'm looking for a little guidance in making it work. Right off, I know I have at least two issues: 1 there are too many variables, and 2 I'm not sure I can pass a variable as a parameter for the setActiveRange() class. So, my questions:

How can I clean this up? And what (class?) should I be using in order to make it functional?

PS - I still consider myself a novice when it comes to JavaScript. I have the knowledge, but the practical application is something I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure if you need to use script to do what you are trying. Why not use a query formula?

For example:

=query(MasterData!:A:E,"SELECT D,E WHERE A = 'Miranda'",0)

There is some help on queries [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en). You can also query across spreadsheets. That is to say you could assign Miranda her own spreadsheet, which feeds from your master data.

Please share with me a sample spreadsheet data if you need more assistance.

Comment: I believe the range needs to include columns D and E if they are the ones being shown: `=query(MasterData!:A:E,"SELECT D,E WHERE A = "Miranda"",0)`

Comment: I had thought about using a query, but wouldn't each individual teacher have to put the query in every time they wanted to import? Also, this is a small sample of some of the functionality they want, but is the founding piece. All of the other stuff will be easy to implement, but I thought it would be better served by using a function that they can select from the menu

Comment: [Here is the sheet in question](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RC3-m1pnzjO2zgw4TwA5_PvK2dJZ4DwEPDml7yoRQmU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I copied your sheet to [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iVRyNioAp5BZUovtDycbsqzorQl22TktRy1iuwb6YvE/edit#gid=1377446903). Please see the Miranda tab and cell A2 Where I have added a formula. To answer your about question updating the query, queries run in real time, and changes made in the data update in the query right away.

Comment: I may just switch to this, and similar queries for the other functionality I need, thanks!